# How do you make JS EventListeners work in Rails 6 / webpacker?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a web app using Ruby 2.7.1 and Rails 6.0.3.2. On a page, I want an html popover to appear when the user clicks a button. I have some vanilla JS code that just removes a `is-hidden` class from my popover div as the user clicks the button, thus making the popover visible.

```
app/javascript/packs/project.js:

document.addEventListener('turboLinks:load', function () {
    const createProjectButton = document.getElementById('create-project-button')
    const projectPopover = document.getElementById('create-project-popover')

    if (createProjectButton && projectPopover) {
        createProjectButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            return projectPopover.classList.contains('is-hidden') ? projectPopover.classList.remove('is-hidden') : null
        }, false)

        const cancelProjectPopover = document.getElementById('cancel-project-popover')
        cancelProjectPopover.addEventListener('click', function () {
            return projectPopover.classList.add('is-hidden')
        }, false)
    }
})
```

I only want this functionality on one specific page of my application right now, so I've included `project.js` in the respective html file using a pack tag.

```
app/views/project/index.html.erb:

<html>
   <body>
      ...
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'project' %>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, this code does not work as intended. Clicking the corresponding button does not make my popover appear. I can confirm that the js file is correctly included in my application, as any `console.log` statement that I place in `project.js` will appear in the browser console. The js code in `project.js` is from a tutorial that used Rails 5, so I'm guessing it could have something to do with the recent switch from the asset pipeline to webpack.

Comment: Did you initialize turbolinks somewhere? Isn’t the event name all lowercase, i.e., “turbolinks:load”?

Comment: thank you!! That completely fixed it. I would never have guessed that that's actually case sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```
document.addEventListener('turboLinks:load', function () {
```

As you can see, it listens for the 'turboLinks:load' event, which won't happen in an application without TurboLinks.

Remember that javascript will execute immediately if you don't specify triggers (at which time your button will simply be unknown to your browser), so change this line to something like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
```

And your code will run as intended. Also note that I'm adding a listener to 'window' and not 'document', pay attention to which objects have which available event triggers.